# How to send params in an API call using Flutter when structure is Form-data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an API call using Flutter wherein I have send this payload:

[image]

How do I write its code. I have tried modifying my API call

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postHttpMethodFormData(
      {@required String? url, required Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    var header = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Accept-Encoding":
          "gzip, deflate, br" /* 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',*/ /* 'x-org-id': ''*/
    };
    kDebugPrint("Post URL -- '$endPointUrl$url'");
    kDebugPrint("Post Data -- '$data'");
    kDebugPrint("Post Header -- '$header'");
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("$endPointUrl$url"),
      headers: header,
      body: data,
    );
    kDebugPrint("Post Response Code -- '${response.statusCode}'");
    kDebugPrint("Post Response -- '${response.body}'");
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      return {
        'body': response.body,
        'headers': response.headers,
        'error': null,
      };
    } else {
      kDebugPrint("In Post 'else - ${response.statusCode}'");
      return {
        'body': response.body,
        'headers': response.headers,
        'error': "${response.statusCode}",
      };
    }
  }
```

I get an exception

```
E/flutter (23165): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "multipart/form-data".
E/flutter (23165): #0      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:133:7)
E/flutter (23165): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
E/flutter (23165): #2      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (23165): #3      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:71:16)
E/flutter (23165): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (23165): #5      post (package:http/http.dart:70:5)
E/flutter (23165): #6      HttpHandler.postHttpMethodFormData (package:busineswise/utils/network_http/http_handler.dart:109:41)
```

whats happening and how do I remove this?

Comment: you can change 'Content-type' 
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',